# GMP4J на андроиде с помощью ndk

Tags: java, android

Нашел [проект](https://github.com/altmind/GMP4J)  который создает подобие `java.math.BigInteger` на основе **GMP**.

Что я имею:

- java 8 update 131
- jdk1.8.0_131
- android-ndk-r7c
- cygwin 2.877

Вот мой проект в ndk: [ссылка](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6GM5/txLbWYneD)

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := gmp4j
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/ \ C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/include/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := us_altio_gmp4j_BigInteger.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

При постройке **.so** библиотеки через **cygwin** в **ndk-build** постоянно получаю ошибку.
Не могу понять что не так.
Заранее спасибо.

И как можно это сделать без cygwina, напрямую в windows???

Comment: Без лога ошибки будет сложно что-то вам посоветовать. И оффтопик - зачем вы собираете через cygwin? Напрямую в Windows религия не позволяет?

Comment: Вот лог: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/BRMt/xuzkXmFxC

Comment: Вставьте логи в свой вопрос, неужели вы думаете, что кто-то полезет в это дурацкое облако?!

Comment: вставил в ответ